# Mysql to html table with linebreaks \r\n as one row

Tags: php, mysql, line-breaks

I have mysql table

With 3 columns: id, name, number.

Some of the name, number fields have more than one enetry, but they are seperated with \r\n linebreak. But there are allways the same amount of enterys in name and number.

Example:

```
name; number
First\r\n; fists\r\n
Second\r\n third\r\n; Second\r\n third\r\n
```

How can i get them appear in html table as different rows.

ive tried to make this happen with:

```
if(strpos($string, "\r\n") !== FALSE) {
```

But this only get me so far as i know when there is more than 1 entry.
And as even with one entry i still have linebreak its not realy helping

Comment: i am trying to this on the output side. they allready are in mysql like that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode` for separating the lines from your SQL result.
http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php

```
$nameFromDatabase = "a \r\n b \r\n c";
$numberFromDatabase = "1 \r\n 2 \r\n 3";

$names = explode("\r\n", $nameFromDatabase);
$numbers = explode("\r\n", $numberFromDatabase);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($names) && $i < count($numbers); $i++) {
    echo "<tr><td>" + $names[i] + "</td><td>" + $numbers[i] + "</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Stupid me :) they was missing $names[i]  but must be $names[$i]

So if u repair the answer then i can giv it a thumbs :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method to bring it to a table:

```
$str = 'name; number
First\r\n; fists\r\n
Second\r\n third\r\n; Second\r\n third\r\n';

$exploded = explode('\r\n',$str);
array_walk($exploded,function(&$value){
    $value = '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
});

echo '<table><tr>'.implode('</tr><tr>',$exploded).'</tr></table>';
```